# How to make the aws command available to sh when using the ansible shell module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, sh, aws-cli

I'm trying to run the following task by using aws cli, because of the `aws_s3` module flats out all the bucket keys. However, I keep getting `aws: not found` error.
`aws cli` is correctly installed because running the exact same command from the host, works fine.

My task:

```
- name: Try list
  shell: aws s3 ls "{{ s3_bucket }}"
```

The full error:

```
fatal: [cassandra-node-1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "aws s3 ls \"cassandra-snapshotter-test2\"", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.002900", 
    "end": "2019-05-12 13:48:25.705324", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "aws s3 ls \"cassandra-snapshotter-test2\"", 
            "_uses_shell": true, 
            "argv": null, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "stdin": null, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 127, 
    "start": "2019-05-12 13:48:25.702424", 
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: aws: not found", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: aws: not found"
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Why can't I run the aws cli from the Ansible task?

Comment: It is hard to pin down on the source of your problems, but so far two possible questions come to my mind: 1. Is this task being executed on `hosts: localhost` (since I assume that you have the aws cli installed locally). 2. Is the aws cli installed system-wide, or is it installed (and added to the $PATH) only for your user, and for some reason ansible is starting as a different user and has the environment variables cleared.

Comment: Also, while this isn't what you asked, the "ansible-way" of doing what you're trying to do is via [`aws_s3: mode=list bucket={{s3_bucket}}`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/aws_s3_module.html#aws-s3-module)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I mention in my post that using `aws_s3` does not work for me because that gives me all keys flat, whereas `shell: aws s3 ls` gives only the top folders.

Comment: @PiotrWicijowski I'm not running on localhost. The aws cli is on PATH, but apparently, it's an issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25147

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AWS binary is not available to the sh interpreter on this host.

From a shell session run

`$ which aws`

to find where the awscli is located.

Make sure this directory is included in the PATH environment variable

`$ echo $PATH`

If it is not you can either configure your server to include it when a shell is opened

```
# bash
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/awscli/dir'  >> ~/.bash_profile

# KSH/sh
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/awscli/dir'  >> ~/.profile
```

Alternately you can use the ansible [environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) property to set environment variables in memory for a particular play, task, etc.

```
environment:
  PATH: "{{ lookup('env', 'PATH) }}:/path/to/awscli/dir"
```

Finally, for brevity, you can modify the shell ansible is using for the `shell` module in your ansible.cfg using the [executable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) key under the [defaults] section. This would allow you to change it from the sh interpreter to something else like bash.

Comment: Strangely I also see this even when I get ansible to use a bash shell with args: executable: /bin/bash but If I ssh into the aws instance, the AWS executable is available.  I think this is because for some reason /usr/local/sbin is not in the path when running an ansible bash shell.