# Ansible: AWS CLI not working with command or shell module

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, ansible

I'm trying to bring files from S3 to a directory. My Ansible code block (erring at the first task):

```
- name: Transfer scripts to {{ instance_directory_vars.scripts_ovi }} from s3 bucket
  block:         
    - name: Transfer from s3 to local
      shell: "aws s3 cp {{ pg_scripts.s3_loc }}/{{ pg_scripts.fname }} {{ instance_directory_vars.scripts_ovi }}/"
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    - name: Unzip the transferred file
      shell: "unzip {{ instance_directory_vars.scripts_ovi }}/{{ pg_scripts.fname }} -d {{ instance_directory_vars.scripts_ovi }}/"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "{{ admin_group_name }}"
```

The error I'm getting:

```
fatal: [10.0.7.9]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "aws s3 cp s3://ov90-golden/pgscripts.zip /ovi/scripts/",
    "delta": "0:00:00.002329",
    "end": "2021-05-25 11:27:18.390103",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "aws s3 cp s3://ov90-golden/pgscripts.zip /ovi/scripts/",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2021-05-25 11:27:18.387774",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: aws: command not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: aws: command not found"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I've tried replacing `shell` with the `command` module, but that gives me:

```
"cmd": "aws s3 cp s3://ov90-golden/pgscripts.zip /ovi/scripts/",
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "aws s3 cp s3://ov90-golden/pgscripts.zip /ovi/scripts/",
        "_uses_shell": false,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": null,
        "removes": null,
        "stdin": null,
        "stdin_add_newline": true,
        "strip_empty_ends": true,
        "warn": true
    }
},
"msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'aws': b'aws'",
"rc": 2
```

I have also tried removing the double quotes (from `shell/command: "aws ..."`) and using the folded block scalar (`shell: > \n aws ...` ) without luck. The command `aws s3 cp s3://ov90-golden/pgscripts.zip /ovi/scripts/` works fine manually.

EDITS:

Other notable attempts that failed (Error:  `"/bin/sh: aws: command not found"` in both):

```
- name: Transfer from s3 to local
  shell: 
    cmd: "aws s3 cp {{ pg_scripts.s3_loc }}/{{ pg_scripts.fname }} {{ instance_directory_vars.scripts_ovi }}/"
    chdir: "/home/{{ admin_group_name }}/"
```

And

```
- name: Transfer from s3 to local
  shell: 
    cmd: >
     aws s3 cp {{ pg_scripts.s3_loc }}/{{ pg_scripts.fname }} {{ instance_directory_vars.scripts_ovi }}/
    chdir: "/home/{{ admin_group_name }}/"
```

Side question: In the second case (with folded scalar '>'), Ansible adds a newline automatically after the raw command. Why is that? Here's the detailed error for the second case:

```
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "aws s3 cp s3://ov90-golden/pgscripts.zip /ovi/scripts/\n",
        "_uses_shell": true,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": "/home/ovadmin/",
        ...
    }
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101308/8340742 --> This Answer worked for me

Fix - Added:

```
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}:/usr/local/bin/aws"
```

Solved, but I still don't understand why I needed this considering `/usr/local/bin` was already in my PATH and `/usr/local/bin/aws` is just a subset of that directory.

Comment: after banging my head for 12hrs with lot of other approaches, finally this solution worked for me
I was able to execute the below command on the client instance directly but was not working from remote instance through ansible, after setting the PATH like given in this answer it worked.
`aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin accountId.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: im not so lucky, in using win_command and win_shell and need something similar to this for windows...

Answer (score 0):

The error `"stderr": "/bin/sh: aws: command not found"` looks like aws cli is not found on the host. I see you are using sudo so double check by manually trying the command with sudo on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Problem was the PATH variable. Still curious why it worked manually